# Close a file from within python

Tags: python, csv, error-handling, permissions

I have a `py` script that runs every night collecting data from an api and updating a number of `csv files` (using `pandas` `.to_csv`. Sometimes one of the files might be open in excel (because I've been looking at it and forgot to close it). This raises a permission error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:`

I want to trap this error, close the `csv file` (or close excel) without saving, and then try writing to the file again.

Is there a way to do this from within python?

Comment: You cannot close a file opened in another process. But you can terminate the other process. (Which automatically closes all the files opened by that process.)

Comment: OK, so how do I terminate excel?

Comment: I can use os.kill to terminate the process as explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.kill), but first need to identify the process id. How do i do that?

Comment: Here's a possibly helpful external link: http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/11/closing-excel-using-python/. You can give it a try. Not being a Windoz programmer, I cannot validate the proposed method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to catch any IOError for write access, kill excel with windows taskkill command if exception found

```
import os
import time
try:
    with open(r'C:\file.csv', 'a') as f:
        pass
except IOError:
    os.system('taskkill /F /IM excel.exe')
    time.sleep(2)

# do your csv read write, for example
with open(r'C:\file.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('data')
```

Comment: This is great. thanks. I needed a small delay `time.sleep(2)` after calling `taskkill` to give time for excel to fully close, otherwise the error repeated.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need to search if swap file(current opened file) exist in the same directory or not .

If swap file exist then might need to delete that. before writing to that file

Read about it [here](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/definition/swap-file-swap-space-or-pagefile)
FYI: [Delete Swap Files](https://superuser.com/questions/480367/whats-the-easiest-way-to-delete-vim-swapfiles-ive-already-recovered-from) (Not programmatically though)

Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Deleting a swap file does not terminate the process that created it (Excel) and does not close any files opened by that process.